# When the national leader is a foreigner

Tags: nationalism, biography, border

In a [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/41303/28512) about leaders who rose quickly from "nothing" to supreme power, someone suggested Hitler, someone else Napoleon, then it was noticed that Hitler was a foreigner (Austrian who came into power in Germany), then it was remarked that Napoleon was Corsican (not exactly a foreigner, but anyway borderline French).

And then I notice that Stalin was Georgian, Victor Emmanuel Piedmontese, Bismarck Prussian, Getúlio Vargas a Gaúcho. All of them either "foreign" to the (most important) nation they led, or at least coming from the farthest borders of that nation.

To ask about the causes of such pattern (or whether it is a mere coincidence) would probably be deemed too broad or opinion-based to be properly answered.

So, to be objective, is there any study, book or paper, that deals with this curious set of facts?

(To notice, I am not talking about dynastic issues. True, many princes become sovereigns in foreign nations, through marriage or invitation, but that's not the issue. I am talking about actual leaders, i.e., people who won elections or revolutions or staged *coup d'etats*)

Comment: The names in you second paragraph are rather bizarre. Bismarck was a Prussian serving the king of Prussia who federated the German states. By your account, any prime minister of the German Empire would have been a "foreigner". Stalin was not a foreigner, since Georgia was already in the Russian empire which had almost the same territory as the USSR. Victor Emmanuel could not have been an Italian, because there was no Italian state before his armies united the country.

Comment: And "Gaúcho" is not a nationality.

Comment: @MichaelBay - Yeah, that's basically South American for "Cowboy". That'd be like throwing Teddy Roosevelt on there for being a "Rough Rider".

Comment: @T.E.D. - Oh well. I am a Gaúcho, and I am certainly no cowboy. So you get your definitions wrong. A Gaúcho is someone born in the Brazilian state of Rio Grande do Sul. And "gaúcho" is a Portuguese word, so it cannot be a general South American term (which would be the Spanish word *gaucho* - still not a generic term for cowboy, but a bit closer).

Comment: Most of the people you mention weren't really "foreginers". The concept that "Austrians are not Germans" dates from 1945 and so coincides with the end of Hitler; before that pretty much everyone in Germany and Austria considered Austrians germans so your argument doesn't hold. Piedmont had always been part of Italy culturally; I don't see how you could call Victor Emmanuel a "foreigner". Same hold for Bismarck and Prussia. So this question is based on completely false premises.

Comment: @LuísHenrique So, a person like you from the Brazilian state of Rio Grande do Sul is not Brazilian? Is there a new separatist movement there that hasn't made the news yet? PS - "Gaúcho" and "gaucho" *is* the same word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaucho#Etymology). Being of Portuguese origin is one hypothesis but not even the preferred one by the majority of the linguists. What we know for sure is that the earliest document mentioning it is from Argentina, a former Spanish territory, therefore it could have been the other way around.

Comment: And yes, it means "cowboy": *The gaucho in some respects resembled members of other nineteenth century rural, horse-based cultures such as the North American cowboy (vaquero, in Spanish), the Chilean huaso, the Peruvian chalan, and morochuco, the Venezuelan or Colombian llanero, the Hawaiian paniolo, the Mexican charro or the Portuguese campino*, according to Wikipedia. Does it need to be edited/corrected?

Comment: @MichaelBay Please trust the self-identified person from Rio Grande do Sul about the implications of his own demonym. I don't think he needs to be corrected. RS is a border region with separatist tendencies and the question makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a false premise (Napoleon, Hitler, Bismarck, Victor Emanuel being "foreigners" when they weren't.)

Comment: @AaronBrick It = Wikipedia, that's what I was asking about, whether or not that Wiki entry needs to be edited/corrected, not the OP or the question. However, the premises are still false no matter from what angle you look at it. No one of the quoted leaders fashioned themselves as "foreigners" to the nations they led, all the opposite for most actually, and especially for the *gaucho* Vargas.

Comment: @MichaelBay Well, of course a Gaúcho is a Brazilian. Aren't Texans North Americans, or are Sicilians not Italians? I am a Gaúcho, and I am a Brazilian. And this has nothing to do with separatism, otherwise there would be a separatist movement in each state (and in each city) in Brazil, all of them having their own demonyms.

Comment: And of course Wikipedia needs editing, even though it does not deserve it. *Gaucho* is a Spanish word, that, in certain contexts, may mean something vaguely similar to "cowboy" (an Argentinian or Uruguayan cowboy, not a Venezolan cowboy, much less an American cowboy). The Portuguese word *gaúcho* is similar but the contexts in which it can mean something like a cowboy are much more limited; I would say it is a marginal use of the word at most. In any other state of Brazil, it means exclusively "person from Rio Grande do Sul". In Rio Grande do Sul, it usually means that, but can, depending...

Comment: ... on context, mean "person from rural areas", "uneducated person", "person dressed in typical attire", or, less probably, "person who works in husbandry". But Tom Mix is not a *gaúcho*, by no stretch of imagination.

Comment: @BernardMassé - "*or at least coming from the farthest borders of that nation*". Is that not clear?

Answer (score 2):

Historically, this is not a "curious fact" but rather a general rule. I mean the time when "national leaders" in Europe were monarchs. It is very common for a monarch to be a foreigner.

Some examples: William I and William III of England, and their descendants,
Romanov's dynasty in Russia after Peter I was mostly German. And most other European monarchs.

Answer (score 1):

A foreigner as a ruler is (or perhaps was) quite common in Europe. Many  European emerging nations looked for (usually) German princes when they gained their independence, if they wanted to become a kingdom and didn't have a royal family. The supplying royal families found this an excellent way to employ their sons not in line for the throne.

Why German princes? Because Germany had many, very many, princedoms and smaller kingdoms.

The Belgian kings descent from a German prince. So does the Dutch royal family, be it by now very indirect. The direct bloodline died out a couple of times. That Dutch royal family briefly occupied the throne of England, under William III.

To be precise, William I of Orange was a French, not a German prince. Originally he was heir to the county of Nassau, before he inherited the French principality of Orange. There is much more to that, but that is outside the scope of this question.

The British royal family changed their name from [Saxe-Coburg-Gotha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert,_Prince_Consort) into [Windsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Windsor) during WW1 for obvious reasons. The [Saxe-Coburg-Gotha family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Saxe-Coburg_and_Gotha) was a German royal family.

George I of Greece was a Danish prince. Ferdinand I of Bulgaria was a German prince. Czar Ferdinand I of Bulgaria was also a German prince.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_I_of_Belgium
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Silent
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_of_Nassau
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Orange
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountbatten_family
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_I_of_Greece
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_I_of_Romania
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_I_of_Bulgaria